Optimize performance Euler problem 12 in a Julia oneliner
I recently started coding in Julia (coming from Python).
To practice my Julia skills, I started solving Euler problems.
Euler problem 12 (https://projecteuler.net/problem=12) is not so hard to solve.
To make things a little harder, I try to solve each problem one line of code, sometimes with a helper function.
The code below gives the right answer, but does not perform well (takes 3 minutes).
function factors(n)
    treshold = 500
    counter = 0
    s = sum(1:n)
    for i in 1:s
        if s%i == 0
            counter += 1
        end
    end
    if counter > treshold
        return false
    else
        return true
    end
end

sum(1:maximum(Iterators.takewhile(factors, Iterators.countfrom()))+1)

What a the best options in Julia to speed up this oneliner?

By the way, you can write something like return !(counter > treshold) which compress 5 line into 1 and can be slightly faster. You can also write, counter += (s%i == 0) (shorter and faster). You can even break the loop if the counter reach the threshold too. But the main problem here is the algorithm (especially for prime inputs) as pointed by OscarSmith.

Great suggestion, thanks!

Or return counter <= threshold

The simplest speedup would be to only count up to isqrt(s) instead of s. With
function factors(n)
    treshold = 500
    counter = 0
    s = sum(1:n)
    for i in 1:isqrt(s)
        if i*i == s
            counter += 1
        elseif s%i == 0
            counter += 2
        end
    end
    if counter > treshold
        return false
    else
        return true
    end
end

This takes only 0.07 seconds.
